# Spring使用中の、Mavenでのビルド失敗を解決したい

Tags: java, spring, maven

Spring Frameworkで、環境構築が成功しているかのチェックをしています。
shopというプロジェクトとパッケージを作成してMavenを実行しようとしたところ、以下のエラーメッセージが発生しました。

```
ビルド・パス問題

必須ライブラリーのアーカイブ：
プロジェクト 'shop' の 'pom.xml' を読み込めないか、有効な ZIP ファイルではありません
```

Answer (score 1):

おそらく、EclipseかSTSを使っているのではないかと思いますが、`pom.xml`をビルドパスに追加してしまっているんだと思います。プロジェクト「shop」のビルドパスから`pom.xml`を削除してみて下さい。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 迅速なご回答、感謝いたします。

Comment: 解決したら、[承認](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)しておいて下さい。